# Find $\lim_{x \to a^+} \frac{\cos(x)\ln(x-a)}{\ln(e^x-e^a)}$ using L'Hospital's Rule.

Tags: calculus, limits

I am having a hard time figuring out how to find $\lim_{x \to a^+} \frac{\cos(x)\ln(x-a)}{\ln(e^x-e^a)}$ using L'Hospital's Rule. I differentiate the numerator and denominator, but I'm not sure what to do with the result. This is my first time working with a limit where $x \to a^+$ instead of a known number like zero. If I just plug in $a^+$ the answer seems to become $\cos(a)$ but I need to use L'Hospital's Rule.

$$\lim_{x \to a^+} \frac{\cos(x)\ln(x-a)}{\ln(e^x-e^a)} = \lim_{x \to a^+} \frac{\frac{d}{dx}\cos(x)\ln(x-a)}{\frac{d}{dx}\ln(e^x-e^a)}$$

$$\frac{d}{dx} \ln(x - a)=\frac{x}{x - a} \to \frac{d}{dx}\cos(x)\ln(x-a) = -\sin(x)\ln(x-a)+\frac{\cos(x)}{x-a}$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}\ln(e^x-e^a) = \frac{e^x}{e^x-e^a}$$

$$\lim_{x \to a^+} \frac{\frac{d}{dx}\cos(x)\ln(x-a)}{\frac{d}{dx}\ln(e^x-e^a)} = \lim_{x \to a^+}\frac{-\sin(x)\ln(x-a)+\frac{\cos(x)}{x-a}}{\frac{e^x}{e^x-e^a}}$$

This is where I get stuck. How can I handle this?

Comment: You made mistakes in the derivatives of $\cos x$ and for $\ln(x-a)$

Comment: @Andrei Thank you, I have fixed it.

Comment: $\frac d{dx}\ln(x-a)=\frac1{x-a}$, no extra $x$

Comment: @Andrei Whoops, thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $x-a=h$ in $$\dfrac{\ln(x-a)}{a+\ln(e^{x-a}-1)}$$

Then apply L'hospital rule

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? I'm only a calc 1 student, and I'm not really sure what you're saying. How should I set $x-a=h$ into that?

Comment: @LuminousNutria, As the limit for $\cos$ is non zero finite, I've left that as an exercise. Replace all occurrences of $x-a$ with $h$ and $$h\to0^+$$

Comment: Thank you, I have worked through it, but I can't seem to find a way to make $\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{ln(h)}{a+\ln(e^h-1)}$ be a defined number. Once L'Hospital's rule is applied, it becomes $\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{\frac{1}{h}}{\frac{e^h}{e^h-1}}$ I have tried multiplying by $\frac{e^h}{e^h}$ and just doing $\frac{1}{h} \cdot \frac{e^h-1}{e^h}$ but neither results in what I want.

Comment: @LuminousNutria your $\frac {e^h-1}{h \cdot (e^h)}$ is correct. Just take derivative one more time before applying limit $h \to 0$

Comment: Oh! I see! Can we differentiate both numerator and denominator however many times we want to get the answer?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is $$\lim_{x\to a^+}\frac{\cos x \cdot ln(x-a)}{ln(e^x-e^a)}$$
Here, as $x\to a$, $\cos x \to cos a$, which will be a constant between $0$ and $1$.
So, let us reduce our problem to: $$\lim_{x \to a^+} \frac{ln(x-a)}{ln(e^x-e^a)}$$
Using L'Hospital Rule, let us take first derivative of given function:
It becomes: $$\lim_{x \to a^+}\frac{e^x-e^a}{e^x \cdot (x-a)}$$ 
For $x \to a^+$, this again becomes $\frac 00$ form.
Taking derivative, we get: $$\frac{e^x}{e^x\cdot (1+x-a)}$$ or $$\frac 1 {1+x-a}$$
Now put the limit to get $1$
Multiply with $\cos x$ we left earlier, for $x \to a^+$, i.e. $\cos a$:

> **Final answer is: $\cos a$**

Comment: How do you get to step 3 $\lim_{x \to a^+}\frac{e^x-e^a}{e^x \cdot (x-a)}$ there? I thought $\frac{d}{dx} \ln(x-a) = \frac{1}{x-a}$ and $\frac{d}{dx} \ln(e^x-e^a) = \frac{e^x}{e^x-e^a}$.

Comment: @LuminousNutria yes you are correct. Just divide them both, you will reach to step 3.

Answer (score -2):

The cosine can be set to cos(a), while the remaining
can be calculated with the rule.
Applied twice -first we get
exp (-x) (exp x - exp a)/(x - a)
Then second time - we find exp(a-x).
Which has limit 1
Hence the final answer is:
cos(a)

Comment: you forgot an $e^x$ in denominator, from derivative of $ln(e^x-e^a)$